# Javascript Conditional Inside TypeScript Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to have a condition inside of an interface declaration in TypeScript. What I'm looking for is a way to say, based on the value of the first key, the second key can be these values.

Example (non functioning):

```
interface getSublistValue {

    /** The internal ID of the sublist. */
    sublistId: 'item' | 'partners';

    /** The internal ID of a sublist field. */
    if (this.sublistId === 'item') {
        fieldId: 'itemname' | 'quantity';
    }

    if (this.sublistId === 'partners') {
        fieldId: 'partnername' | 'location';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No there's not. The best thing to do is to create separate interfaces that describe the two different types of data.

For example:

```
interface SublistItem {
    sublistId: 'item';
    fieldId: 'itemname' | 'quantity';
}

interface SublistPartners {
    sublistId: 'partners';
    fieldId: 'partnername' | 'location';
}

function getData(): SublistItem | SublistPartners {
    return (Math.random() < 0.5)
        ? { sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'itemname' }
        : { sublistId: 'partners', fieldId: 'partnername' };
}

const someValue = getData();

if (someValue.sublistId === "item") {
    // SublistItem in here
}
else {
    // SublistPartners in here
}
```

Comment: So if I use this method when I'm creating the `someValue` object I still get all 4 options for `fieldId` with autocomplete, but at least it gives me a warning if the sublistId and fieldId don't match (i.e. 'item' and 'partnername'). The thing that gets me is that if my `someValue` is `const someValue: SublistItem | SublistPartners = {
    sublistId: 'partners',
    fieldId: 'location'
};` then I get a warning on the `if (someValue.sublistId === 'item') {}` condition saying that `location` is not `itemname` or `quantity`, I already know that, why would I get that warning?

Comment: @JonLamb hmmm... the error message displayed for that isn't helpful. In that case, it knows that `sublistId` will only be `'partners'` and so it throws an error when you check for `'item'`. If you replace `'item'` with `'partners'` then it will work. Try a scenario where you are receiving a value from somewhere and you're not sure what the data will be. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 15):

If you would like to completely separate out your interfaces you could do something like this:

eg. **sublist.model.ts**

```js
interface SublistItem {
    sublistId: 'item';
    fieldId: 'itemname' | 'quantity';
}

interface SublistPartners {
    sublistId: 'partners';
    fieldId: 'partnername' | 'location';
}

export type Sublist = SublistItem | SublistPartners;
```

Now you can use the Sublist type and it will correctly infer whether it is of type SublistPartners or SublistItem depending on the field values you provide.

Comment: That is the perfect answer I was looking for, thanks

Comment: very fantastic, thankyou bro...

Comment: Thank you  seems so simple once you see it!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to solve this problem using conditional types:

```js
interface SublistItem {
    sublistId: 'item';
    fieldId: 'itemname' | 'quantity';
}

interface SublistPartners {
    sublistId: 'partners';
    fieldId: 'partnername' | 'location';
}

type ConditionalSublist<bIsSublistItem=true> = bIsSublistItem extends true ? SublistItem : SublistPartners;

let sublistItem: ConditionalSublist<true> = {
    fieldId: "itemname",
    sublistId: "item"
};

let sublistPartner: ConditionalSublist<false> = {
    fieldId: "partnername",
    sublistId: "partners"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use my example. After providing required props, typescript will suggest other props.

```
interface _ButtonProps {
  variant: 'flat' | 'primary';
}

interface FlatButton extends _ButtonProps {
  variant: 'flat';
  textColor?: string;
}

interface PrimaryButton extends _ButtonProps {
  variant: 'primary';
  backgroundColor?: string;
}

export type ButtonProps = FlatButton | PrimaryButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

For interfaces unfortunately not but for types Yes there is and its fairly clean

```
type getSublistValue = {
     sublistId: 'item';
     fieldId: 'itemName' | 'quantity'; 
 } & {
     sublistId:'partners';
    fieldId: 'partnerName' | 'location';
}
```

Here is a great [video](https://youtu.be/9i38FPugxB8?si=MayR8zxrnVjgfoHq) explaining how to do it clean with types