# Conditional types with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

Say I have this:

```
type TypeMapping = {
  Boolean: boolean,
  String: string,
  Number: number,
  ArrayOfString: Array<string>,
  ArrayOfBoolean: Array<boolean>
}

export interface ElemType {
  foo: keyof TypeMapping,
  default: valueof TypeMapping
}
```

instead of using `any` for default, I want to conditionally define it, I tried this:

```
export interface ElemType<T extends TypeMapping> {
  foo: keyof T,
  default: T
}
```

but that doesn't seem quite right, does anyone know the right way to do this?

if it's not clear, for any given object that has type ElemType, the key that foo points to, must be matched by the value that foo points to. For example, this is valid:

```
{
  foo: 'String',
  default: 'this is a string'
}
```

but this is not:

```
{
  foo: 'Boolean',
  default: 'this should be a boolean instead'
}
```

so the type of the default field is *conditional* on the value/type of the type field.

**Succintly**, if `foo` is `'ArrayOfBoolean'`, then `default` should be: `Array<boolean>`.  If `foo` is `'Number'`, then default should be `number`, if foo is `'Boolean'` then default should be `boolean`, etc etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Conditional Inside TypeScript Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211804/javascript-conditional-inside-typescript-interface)

Comment: I updated the OP, the questions seem to be different or at least the answer to that question is not sufficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `ElemType` as in Catalyst's answer and then use a mapped type to take the union of `ElemType` for all possible `K`:

```
interface ElemType<K extends keyof TypeMapping> {
  foo: K;
  default: TypeMapping[K];
}
type ElemTypeMap = {[K in keyof TypeMapping]: ElemType<K>};
// type ElemTypeMap = {
//   Boolean: {foo: "Boolean", default: boolean},
//   String: {foo: "String", default: string},
//   ...
// }
type SomeElemType = ElemTypeMap[keyof TypeMapping];
// Look up in ElemTypeMap by all keys and take the union:
// {foo: "Boolean", default: boolean} | {foo: "String", default: string} | ...
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you last line is doing - not sure what the accessor portion - you have a standard interface `{}` but then accessed `{}[]`

Comment: This is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).  When the type in the `[]` is a union of multiple keys, it produces the union of the value types of those keys.  See the updated answer.  Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell typescript to validate the actual obj somehow, and you can't really escape without using generics; this is how I would do it:

```
type TypeMapping = {
  Boolean: boolean;
  String: string;
  Number: number;
  ArrayOfString: Array<string>;
};

export interface ElemType<K extends keyof TypeMapping> {
  foo: K;
  default: TypeMapping[K];
}

const Elem = <E extends keyof TypeMapping, T extends ElemType<E>>(t: ElemType<E>) => t;

Elem({ foo: "Boolean", default: true }); //yup
Elem({ foo: "Boolean", default: "" }); //nope
```