# How to go from a mapped type to a discriminated union

Tags: typescript

Apologises if this question has already been asked. I tried hard to find the solution but I'm probably not searching with the right terms.

My problem starts with this structure. This is a simple mapped type:

```
type Mapped = {
  square: {
    size: number;
  };
  rectangle: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
};
```

I then have a type that it trying to create a union:

```
type Unionize<T> = {
  name: keyof T;
  data: T[keyof T];
};

type Out = Unionize<Mapped>;
```

It yields this type:

```
type Generated = {
  name: "square" | "rectangle";
  data: {
    size: number;
  } | {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
}
```

But really what I would like is this because I then would be able the leverage discriminated union to infer and check data properties.

```
type Wanted = {
  name: "square";
  data: {
    size: number;
  };
} | {
  name: "rectangle";
  data: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating the `name` and `data` types independently using `keyof T`, first use a mapped type to put together the correct `name` and `data` for each key of `T` and then index that by `keyof T` to take the union.

```
type Unionize<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: {
    name: P;
    data: T[P];
  }
}[keyof T];
```

Comment: Correct answer.. But maybe explain a bit why his was wrong and yours is right... It hard to upvote code snippets...(although I did :-) )

Comment: It's hard to be enthusiastic about writing an explanation when I doubt the OP needs it and it's doubtful that anyone else with the same problem will find this thread in the future.  But I was bored, so there, I did it. :)

Comment: You never know who ends up finding these .. I received upvotes on questioned I answered months ago that I never thought anybody would ever dig up :)

Comment: Actually @MattMcCutchen I really appreciate your explanation. I've been trying hard to find by myself. So as much as I'm grateful for the practical solution having the reasoning behind (that's I was missing) is even more interesting 

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I realised now you essentially answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175735. You are right that it is hard to find.